MacBook Pro 14 M1 Pro treating Dell WD19TB only as power source
I purchased a Dell WD19TB (Thunderbolt 3) to use it with my Gigabyte M27Q screen. I connected the screen to the dock using a Thunderbolt 3 cable and connected a mouse and keyboard. I am using an external power source adapter with 180W.
However, even without the screen, the dock is not recognized by the MacBook. It only treats it as a power source and charges the MacBook but doesn't detect the mouse and the keyboard at all.
If I go to system information, I don't see any Thunderbolt port having a device connected to it.
Do I have a defective unit or am I doing something wrong?

I did not find documentation stating the Gigabyte M27Q supports Thunderbolt. The Dell WD19TB may need a firmware upgrade which can only be performed through the use of a Dell computer.

I updated the firmware to latest using a windows laptop.

In all cases, I'm trying the docking station without the screen and even then, mouse and keyboard don't get detected. The docking station seems to be only passing power and not data for some reason. I suspect something with the charge negotiation but couldn't find a solution

Does the Windows laptop (used to update the firmware on the docking station) detect the mouse, keyboard and/or screen when these devices are connected to the docking station and the docking station is connected to the laptop?

Yes they work without any issue on the windows laptop through the docking station @DavidAnderson
